Odoo17.0 CE - Website - Uncaught Promise > An error occured in the owl lifecycle (see this Error's "cause" property)
OwlError: An error occured in the owl lifecycle (see this Error's "cause" property)
    Error: An error occured in the owl lifecycle (see this Error's "cause" property)
        at handleError (https://example.com/web/assets/2d24580/web.assets_web.min.js:916:101)
        at App.handleError (https://example.com/web/assets/2d24580/web.assets_web.min.js:1545:29)
        at RootFiber.complete (https://example.com/web/assets/2d24580/web.assets_web.min.js:947:37)
        at Scheduler.processFiber (https://example.com/web/assets/2d24580/web.assets_web.min.js:1516:43)
        at Scheduler.processTasks (https://example.com/web/assets/2d24580/web.assets_web.min.js:1511:62)
        at https://example.com/web/assets/2d24580/web.assets_web.min.js:1509:67

Caused by: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'body')
    at https://example.com/web/assets/2d24580/web.assets_web.min.js:15660:47
    at MenuDialog.<anonymous> 

I try to edit Odoo Website and appears this error. When I choose edit the system keeps no resolving, and I can't go to edition.

In back-office, go to Settings and at the bottom of the page, click on "Regenerate assets"

Add ?debug=1 in the url of your back-office (see image below).
Go to Settings, in the top-menu: >Technicals >Views.
In the view panel : on the right side of the top-menu: click on the "Bug"-icon>Edit View List

add the column id:
<field name="id" />

and then click on this column (ID)-header to "sort desc", to find the last edited view that you have customized... Click on this view and set it as inactive


Thanks Ahrimann,In back-office, go to Settings and at the bottom of the page, click on "Regenerate assets" but still the same owlerror.
I went to Settings >Technicals >Views. But I don't know how to add the column:ID (using xStudio). Could you help me with this?

Thanks Ahrimann, by this column (ID) I find the last edited view that I have customized... then set the identified views as inactive. But the owl error remains the same.

Clear your browser history completely and regenerate the assets bundle

Good morning Ahrimann! I clear our browser history completely and regenerate the assets bundle, but stay the same.

make sure you have undone your own customization and/or inactivate the right customized view. Please check wether the error remains the same or not

Hi Ahrimann! I make sure that I have undone our own customization and inactivate it. The owlerror remains the same presented at the begining of this question.

Hi Ahrimann! how are you? Do you have any other idea how to review this owlerrol? Best regards and thanks!
